# почему он дает ошибку пишите называние interface если я написал уже (в чем проблема )

Tags: python, консоль, subprocess, kali-linux, mac-address

почему он дает ошибку  пишите называние interface если  я написал уже (в чем проблема )

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import optparse

def get_arguments():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest="interface", help="Interface to change its MAC address")
    parser.add_option("-m", "--mac", dest="new_mac", help="New MAC address")
    (options, arguments) = parser.parse_args()
    if not options.interface:
        parser.error("[-] Please specify an interface, use --help more info ")
    elif options.new_mac:
        parser.error("[-] Please specify a new mac, use --help more info")
    return options

def change_mac(interface, new_mac):
    print("[+] Changing MAC address for " + interface + " to " + new_mac)
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"])
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "hw", "ether", new_mac])
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "up"])

options = get_arguments()
change_mac(options.interface, options.new_mac)
```

```
terminal

 sudo python3 mac_changer.py -i eth0 -m 00:11:22:54:77:88 

Usage: mac_changer.py [options]

mac_changer.py: error: [-] Please specify a new mac, use --help more info
```

Comment: добавьте строку вызова к вопросу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if not options.interface:
    parser.error("[-] Please specify an interface, use --help more info ")
elif options.new_mac:
    parser.error("[-] Please specify a new mac, use --help more info")
return options
```

Вы сначала проверяете, что **не указана** опция `-i` и выводите ошибку в этом случае, а потом проверяете, что **указана** опция `-m` и выводите ошибку в этом случае. А проверять нужно, что она тоже **не указана**:

```
if not options.interface:
    parser.error("[-] Please specify an interface, use --help more info ")
elif not options.new_mac:
    #^^^ проверяем, что НЕ указана опция
    parser.error("[-] Please specify a new mac, use --help more info")
return options
```